# JS Grid filter on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I have a JSGRID where I implemented filtering like this:

```
    criteria = filter;
    var d = $.Deferred();               
                if (DATA) {
                var filteredData = $.grep(DATA, function(item, idx) {
                    for (var key in filter) {
                        var value = filter[key].toLowerCase();
                        if (value.length > 0) {
                            if (((item[key]).toString()).toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1)
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
                d.resolve(filteredData);  
                return d.promise();
```

DATA is a local copy of my json object (to save a trip to the server when I only want to filter).

This all is working fine but now I added a checkbox field to the grid. Now when I filter I get an error: " Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'"

I guess I try to lowercase a (type) checkbox field. I cannot find out how to change my code so the filtering works on all kind of fields.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: you should console log the value of `item[key]` before you try to cast it to a string and lowercase it to see what's going on, it looks like you may be storing the checkbox itself rather than the value of it

Comment: Well, the filter object (all possible filterfields) has all strings in it except my checkbox fields which is "undefined". So here we have a problem but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Right, so however you're passing the checkbox data in is probably incorrect. Without seeing the code, my best guess is that you're trying to use `.value` when you need to be checking for `checked` state

Comment: The passing is done bij JSGrid (a bit black box for me). I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Ah ok. Well unless it's doing something really strange, the value returned from a checkbox will never be a string, so that line of logic is failing as it should. `filter[key]` probably isn't a string - I think from looking around js-grid is capable of returning `true`, `false`, or `undefined` from a checkbox

Comment: Yes indeed. It is returning true, false or undefined. So what does that mean for my filterdata function. Howto avoid the error and filter the records based on the checkbox?

Comment: You'd need a slightly more complicated logic tree and somehow get the label/name of the checkbox associated with it. I'll put the logic with a placeholder for that label/name in an answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var filteredData = $.grep(DATA, function(item, idx) {
  for (var key in filter) {
    var value = filter[key]
    if(typeof value === "string"){
      if (value.length > 0 && item[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === -1){
              return false;
      }
    } else {
      if(value === undefined){ 
      
      }
      else if(value){ //checkbox is checked
        //do something to compare the value to the label/name
      } else { //checkbox is false
        
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will give me a start!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code:

```
 loadData: function(filter) {    
            criteria = filter;
            var d = $.Deferred();               
                            if (DATA) {
                var filteredData = $.grep(DATA, function(item, idx) {
                    for (var key in filter) {
                        if(typeof filter[key] === "string"){
                            var value = filter[key].toLowerCase();
                            if (value.length > 0) {
                                if (((item[key]).toString()).toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1)
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            var value2 = filter[key]
                            if (filter[key] === undefined){
                                return true;
                            }
                            else if (item[key] != value2) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
                d.resolve(filteredData);  
                return d.promise();
            }
```

If filter[key] is undefined there is no filter on the checkbox so all records have to be shown. I have to figure out what to do when other field types are in the grid (integers or date or....) So my solution might not be the best yet.